# Taking int as input in java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I tried using following code for reading int input

```
import java.util.*;
public Add{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
        while(scan.hasNextInt()){
            arr.add(scan.nextInt());
        }
        System.out.println(arr);
    }
}
```

When I run the program with any input say -

```
1 2 4
```

It does not stop till I press `CTRL+c`. I have also tried some other variations(for example tried to read it as array of String but that also did not work) but they are the same.Problem is that I don't want to give the size of the input in advance. How can I parse int from console input?

Comment: It shouldn't stop until you ctrl+c, you've built an infinite loop. You can end it on special input, like 0 or a string like 'done' if you like.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check for certain input and break from the loop as [hasNextInt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29) will wait for input from keyboard. You could solve it by following:

```
int number;
while(scan.hasNextInt()){
    number = scan.nextInt();
    if (number == -1) {//if user types in -1, then you will come out of the loop.
        break;
    }
    arr.add(number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using scanner, you may try the following trick instead of using the `ArrayList` -

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
 int num = sc.nextInt();
 System.out.println("Your entered number is: " + num);
}
```

If you use `hasNextInt()` then you don't have to think about the parsing of number. A token that is not a integer will break out you from the loop.